# In report viewer (rdlc) , how to set the background color of the first column by expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer2008

I have the background color set for the entire row however it does not work for the first column if the color is set to an expression.  If I just set it to a color i.e. red it works just fine. If I insert a dummy column to the left it works just fine (but the dummy column does not work, presumably because it is first??).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still no clue why it happening, add a dummy first column is my current solution.